# Loop Macro formula is not working when macro is ran

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I've created a macro that inserts a vlookup into the activecell if its equal to '#N/A'. The loop macro assigns the Vlookup to every cell but the 'MyRange' is not referencing anything after I run the macro. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
For Each cel In ws.Range("E3:E3000")
    If cel.Text = "#N/A" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="MyRange", RefersToR1C1:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3)
    cel.Value = "=VLOOKUP(MyRange,'Sheet3'!A:B,2,FALSE)"
    End If
Next cel
```

Comment: Just filter for `#N/A` values and then drop your formula in the visible cells (`SpecialCells xlCellTypeVisible`). You should be using `cel.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(.....)`. No need to loop here at all

Comment: And your formula should be: `cel.Value = "=VLOOKUP(" & MyRange.Address & ",'Sheet3'!A:B,2,FALSE)". Otherwise, `MyRange` will be just a string which Excel does not understand what it refers.